# PHP, MySQL: Problem retrieving image url strings from database

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays

I've stored image information in my mysql database like below...

```
id, int(10), PRIMARY KEY
title, varchar(255), utf8_unicode_ci
url, varchar(255), utf8_unicode_ci       example: http://www.blahblah.com/blahblah.png
caption, varchar(255), utf8_unicode_ci
width, int(10)
height, int(10)
entry_id, int(10), FOREIGN KEY
```

I'm trying to grab the urls from all the images by doing the following...

```
<?php

include('connectdb.php');
include_once('functions.php');
include_once('class/class.Image.php');

// get all images for Entry
$imgArray = array();
$imgArray = getEntryImages( 3 );
$imgArray = getImageUrls ( $imgArray );

foreach( $imgArray as $img )
{
    echo $img . ', ';
}

?>
```

Here's the output I get, and the code for getEntryImages() & getImageUrls() below...

Output: 5, 5, M, M, h, h, T, T, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3,

```
function getEntryImages ( $entryID )
{
    $imageArray = array();

    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM images WHERE entry_id = ".$entryID."" ) or die();
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

    foreach ( $row as $image )
    {
        $temp_image = new Image ( $image['id'], $image['title'], $image['url'],
                                  $image['caption'], $image['width'], $image['height'],
                                  $image['entry_id'] );

        array_push( $imageArray, $temp_image );
    }

    return $imageArray;
}
```

---

```
function getImageUrls( $imgArray )
{
    $imageUrls = array();

    foreach ( $imgArray as $image )
    {
        array_push( $imageUrls, $image->getUrl() );
    }

    return $imageUrls;
}
```

If anyone is able to point me in any direction on a possible way to fix this problem I'd greatly appreciate it thanks!

Comment: What is this image library your using?

Comment: Not sure about the image library I'm using. How can I find this out?  I was just storing the images on my server in the location I specify with the 'url' string that is in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're only fetching the array only once:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
```

So it's running a `foreach` on the *fields* of the table and their values, not the entire result set!

You need to fetch the array until `$row` is `NULL`, like this:

```
while($image = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $temp_image = new Image ( $image['id'], $image['title'], $image['url'],
                              $image['caption'], $image['width'], $image['height'],
                              $image['entry_id'] );
    $imageArray[] = $temp_image;
}
```

Comment: doh! knew it was gonna be simple.  Guess I should've taken a break awhile ago ;(  Thanks!